# The Server Date Not Match With My Country Date

Tags: php, datetime

The server date/time  not match with my country date/time
eg server time: 11.30pm ..but my localtime already 5.3am

Comment: Server timezone depends on its configuration.

Comment: where is the server? where is local ?

Comment: From the other hand, please learn how to **ask** questions as there's no question.

Comment: Yes.I'm not familiar with English

Comment: @SDD Andrzej is alluding to a missing question mark. For example, you could've asked `Why is there a difference between local and server time?`

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because server and client are in different [timezones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timezone#Definition).

Always use the "0 timezone" UTC to get equal time representations across the globe. In php, you can get dates in UTC by using the functions prefixed with `gm`, such as [`gmtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php). Alternatively, you can set the timezone in your code with [`default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php):

For example, my local time in Germany is CEST or UTC+2, i.e. 2 hours before UTC:

```
<?php
echo 'Local time (Germany, CEST): ' . strftime('%F %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)') . "\n";
echo 'UTC (England, GMT): '       . gmstrftime('%F %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)') . "\n";
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo 'LA time (US, PDT): '          . strftime('%F %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)') . "\n";
```

This outputs:

```
Local time (Germany, CEST): 2011-07-08 14:24:56 +0200 (CEST)
UTC (England, GMT):         2011-07-08 12:24:56 +0000 (GMT)
LA time (US, PDT):          2011-07-08 05:24:56 -0700 (PDT)
```

Comment: @SDD Added an example to the answer.

Comment: That mean all time zones should specify in the php script?

Comment: @SDD No. If you need a globally identical time, calculate in UTC with `gmtime`. If you want to display the time in the user's timezone, ask the user (or determine it automatically from location/country), and set the appropriate timezone. php's `DateTimeZone class` ([doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)) can help you with that.

Comment: Hi ,phihag I have another quiz.. like this .The form buttons should include <input type="submit" Value="save and New" /> and <input type="submit"/>.So i want to SAVE A RECORD and should be able to add NEW RECORD when the "save and New" button clicked.And finally all records (2 or 3..5 ect) should be add to the database when the submit button clicked.So how write the php code?

Comment: Please use this [link](http://www.infarmax.com/test/price.php) and click any Register Button

Comment: @SDD If this (or any other answer) solves the original question, feel free to accept it. That way, people (including you) can see it has been successfully solved. Now, to your new problem (which should be asked in an another question): Either you store everything client-side (in JavaScript, with a listener that prevents default behavior on the "Add Entry" button), or you store the record on the server in a special table for temporary records and then read them out and write them to the real one as soon as the user submits all records. [continued ...]

Comment: @SDD All in all, you're looking at a programming process that's not really fit for a stackoverflow question, because we deal more with local (small) problems. For the general process (and whether to store a completed record, and where), you'd have to discuss about the [user experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) first, and then ... *implement* it (so you'll need a database, or equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your script to match your localtime change your php timezone.
if you use apache you can use a .htaccess file.

Or just put this before your php code

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Amsterdam' );

//the rest of your code

?>
```

replace 'Europe/Amsterdam' with your own timezone.
have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php for a list of timezones

Comment: Ok thnx.My time-zone is asia.It's OK , But my site view someone from Australia or England ect.So how to display the the date/time for England and Australia user